# Display custom post types by category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I want to create a listing of custom post types in a particular category. I've tried the code below without any success. Can someone *please* show me where I have gone wrong?

The custom post type is called 'property', and the category slug is 'long-term'

```
<?php
    $query= null;
    $args=array(
    'post_type' => 'property',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'long-term'
                                    )
                            )
                    );
            $query = new WP_Query($args);
            
             if ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    
    <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
    
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Double-check the name of the taxonomy. You can see it for example in the URL of taxonomy admin page.

Comment: This looks like it should work... How are you connecting the taxonomy to the post-type?

Comment: I realised where I was going wrong. I was using a custom field for the category not the WP category. So using the WP categories got the result I needed.